The Carathéodory construction in comfortable instalments
I'm learning some (abstract) measure theory and consequently going through the bumpy road of $ 1/2^n $, $\pi $s and $ \lambda $s that starts from the notion of an outer measure on a set and ends with a more or less strong form of the following result:

Let $ X $ be a set. Given a suitable collection $ \mathcal E $ of ``elementary subsets'' of $ X $ and a suitable set function $ \rho\colon \mathcal E\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $, there exists a (unique) ($ \sigma $-finite) measure $ \mu $ on the $ \sigma $-algebra $ \langle \mathcal E\rangle_\sigma $ generated by $ \mathcal E $ such that $ \mu(E) = \rho(E) $ for every $ E\in \mathcal E $.

More than just a four-lane road, this is a road that looks like a (convergent?) series of winding country lanes. I will travel along two of them, corresponding respectively to how the subject is dealt with in Folland's Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Applications and Klenke's Probability Theory.
There are things I don't like about both presentations, and I'm trying to put together a version of the story that suits me better. But I need your help! This mess is too hard for me alone to untangle. In the meantime, I'll ask a few questions.
I'll assume for known the fact that given an outer measure $ \mu $ on some set $ X $, the set of all $ \mu $-measurable (in Carathéodory's sense) subsets of $ X $ is a $ \sigma $-algebra.
Folland's presentation
Folland starts with a reasonable pair of lemmas, but his final version of the main ``extension'' theorem advocated above is not strong enough to satisfy me.
I would prefer to start with less than 1) a premeasure 2) on an algebra as is done in Klenke's, but the problem with his version of the story is that his uses of some of the big theorems (Dynkin's, to cite one) makes things unnecessarily complicated for me.
Anyway, let's see.

Lemma 1(F). Let $ X $ be a set. Let $ \mathcal E $ be a collection of subsets of $ X $ such that $ \emptyset,X\in \mathcal E $. Let $ \rho\colon \mathcal E\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $ be a set function such that $ \rho(\emptyset) = 0 $. Then defining
$$
\mu(A) = \inf\Biggl\{\sum_{j\in \mathbb N} \rho(A_j): \text{$ \{E_j\}_{j\in \mathbb N} $ collection of $ E_j\in \mathcal E $ that covers $ A $}\Biggr\}
$$
for every $ A\subset X $ gives an outer measure $ \mu $ on $ X $.


Lemma 2(F). If in the preceding proposition $ \mathcal E $ is an algebra and $ \rho $ is a premeasure, i.e., whenever $ \{E_j\}_{j\in \mathbb N} $ is a countable collection of mutually disjoint members of $ \mathcal E $ such that $ \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j\in \mathcal E $ then
$$
\rho\Bigr(\bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j\Bigl) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb N}\rho(E_j)\text{,}
$$
then

$ \mu(E) = \rho(E) $ for every (``elementary'') set $ E\in \mathcal E $;
every $ E\in \mathcal E $ is $ \mu $-measurable in the Carathéodory sense;

where $ \mu $ is the outer measure induced by $ \rho $.


Theorem 3(F) (Theorem 1.14 on the book). Let $ X $ be a set. Let $ \mathcal E $ be an algebra of subsets of $ X $. Let $ \rho\colon \mathcal E\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $ be a premeasure. Then:

there exists a measure $ \mu $ on the $ \sigma $-algebra $ \langle \mathcal E\rangle_\sigma $ generated by $ \mathcal E $;
if $ \rho $ is $ \sigma $-finite (i.e., if there exists a countable family $ \{E_j\}_{j\in \mathbb E} $ such that $ X = \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j $ and such that $ \rho(E_j) < +\infty $) then $ \mu $ is the unique extension of $ \rho $ to a measure on $ \langle \mathcal E\rangle_\sigma $.



Proof of the first claim. It's straightforward: $ \mu $ is nothing but the restriction to $ \langle \mathcal E\rangle_\sigma $ of the measure on the Carathéodory $ \sigma $-algebra obtained by restricting the outer measure $ \mu^* $ induced by $ \rho $ on the $ \mu^* $-measurable sets. $ \square $
Proof of the second claim. It's not so straightforward but anyways doable. Observe that it does not dwell on the (in)famous Dynkin's $ \pi $-$ \lambda $ theorem. $ \square $

Klenke's presentation
I find Klenke's version of the story a little messy, but the result he arrives at is strong enough for me.
First of all he start with the following uniqueness lemma.

Lemma 1(K). Let $ X $ be a set. Let $ \mathcal E $ be a $ \pi $-system of subsets of $ X $, i.e. a set of subsets of $ X $ which is closed under finite intersections. Let $ \mu\colon \mathscr \langle \mathcal E\rangle_\sigma\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $ be a measure on the $ \sigma $ algebra generated by $ \mathcal E $. Assume that there is a countable family $ \{E_j\}_{j\in \mathbb N} $ of elements of $ \mathcal E $ such that $ E = \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j $ and $ \mu(E_j) < +\infty $. Then $ \mu $ is uniquely determined by its values on members of $ \mathcal E $.

Observe that using Lemma 1(K) we can prove immediately Theorem 3(F), pt. 2.
At this point I have a question: the proof of the lemma as reported Klenke's book makes use of the Dynkin's theorem in some clever way. Is it possible to avoid it and to extrapolate a proof of this fact from the proof of Theorem 3(F), pt. 2? I think that it should be the case.
He then proceeds as in Folland apart from the fact that it's final version of the ``extension theorem'' is the follwing.

Theorem 2(k). Let $ X $ be a set. Let $ \mathcal E $ be a semiring of subsets of $ X $. Let $ \rho\colon \mathcal E\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $ be an additive, $ \sigma $-subadditive and $ \sigma $-finite set function such that $ \rho(\emptyset) = 0 $. Then there exists a unique $ \sigma $-finite measure $ \mu\colon \langle\mathcal E\rangle_\sigma\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $ on the $ \sigma $-algebra generated by $ \mathcal E $ that extends $ \rho $.

The proof (at least to my eyes) differs significantly from the proof of Theorem 3(F). Is "Why?" a too broad question? I'm still reading the proof but I find it hard to grasp the big picture. I think that an answer might be that prof. Klenke does not state a technical lemma like Lemma 2(F), but instead proves a form of it inside the proof of its main theorem.
I think it would be cool to extrapolate a generalization of Lemma 2(B) from Klenke's proof of Theorem 2(K), but I'm not sure I can.
Final thoughts
I think I've been able to draw some roadmap, but a lot of it still seems artificial and forced. If you feel like providing some bird's eye view of these constructions, apart from answering my questions, by all means feel free to do so :)

I've had good results presenting it with the proof in Dudley's "Real Analysis and Probability." It seems similar to Folland's but is elementary and self-contained; in particular, it doesn't use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.

I have looked at it and it's very well written, but it's final form of the theorem is not general enough for me :(
